# Как отправлять сообщения в канал через бота? Discord bot

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Приведу пример:
Я администратор сервера, я пишу боту в личные сообщения текст например и фото, бот отправляем это сообщение в определенный канал от своего имени. И такие сообщения отправляются только от админа.

Я новичок! Спасибо за любую помощь ..
discord.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать ивент `on_message`

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.text_channels, id='айди канала')
    if not message.guild:
        if message.author.id == 'админ айди':
            await channel.send(message.content)
```

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.text_channels, id='айди канала')
    if not message.guild:
        if message.author.id == 'админ айди':
            await channel.send(message.content)
```

p.s. ds: RAINGM#1941

Comment: Спасибо большое! Скажите пожалуйста, у меня ещё такой вопрос, у меня есть ивент когда кто то подключается к серверу, бот приветствует, и я пытаюсь в приветствие вставить эмоцию свою сервера, прописывая в сообщении :Tets: (название эмоции) но когда бот отправляет сообщение он не отображает эту эмоцию , отображает просто :Test: с ID эмоции тоже самое

Comment: Если emoji анимированный: <a:name:id> без <:name:id>

Comment: Не анимированный

Comment: я написал: <:name:id>

Comment: Это не работает(

Comment: await channel.send(f'Привет {member.mention}! <:Clean:914519761940008981> ')

Пишу так

Comment: а бот на сервере, где emoji?

Comment: Да, возможно нужно устанавливать доп библиотеки для emoji ?

Comment: Нет, не нужно, странно

Comment: Вот и мне не понятно (